# unable to retrieve data from installation table in parse

Tags: java, android

unable to retrieve data from installation table in parse...some notes says it need permission (master key)..can u help me to implement a master key and retrieve data from INSTALLATION table.

here is my code:

public void getVanStatus(final ArrayList itemsArray, final TellerResponse tellerResponse){

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Installation");
    query.whereContains("appName", "PLC Admin").findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            itemsArray.clear();
            if (e == null && list != null) {

                itemsArray.addAll(list);

            }
        tellerResponse.responseReceived(ResponseType.GET_VAN_STATUS, null, e);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user you are using to access the database must not have permission to that table.

Comment: but by deault permission is public ?

Comment: Make sure that table exists and that your connection is pointed to the database that you think you are pointed to.